# Как заставить работать шорткоды в названии сайта Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Заставить шорткоды работать в заголовках можно следующим образом :

```
add_filter( 'the_title', function( $title ) {return do_shortcode($title);} );
```

а как сделать чтобы функция `get_bloginfo('name')` выводила название сайта и обрабатывались шорткоды которые в нем содержатся.

Вообщем нужен некоторый функционал как в qtranslate-x, не могу понять как там это реализовано.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обработайте строку, полученную от `get_bloginfo()` с помощью функции `do_shortcode()`

```
$name = get_bloginfo('name');
$name = do_shortcode( $name );
```

Можно также использовать фильтр:

```
add_filter( 'bloginfo', 'bloginfo_filter', 10, 2);
function bloginfo_filter( $output, $show ) {
    $output = do_shortcode( $output);
    return $output;
}
```

Или

```
if( !is_admin() ) {
add_filter( 'option_blogname', 'blogname_filter');
function blogname_filter( $output ) {
$output=do_shortcode( $output);
return $output;
}
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а как сделать то чтоб везде и плагинах и в шаблоне, где  название сайта выводится с помощью get_bloginfo(), работали шорткоды, только руками менять get_bloginfo('name'); на $name?

Comment: я не могу понять как реализован вывод названия сайта в плагине qtranslate-x, когда оно выглядит примерно так: [:en]Blog[:ru]Блог

Comment: Добавил в ответ про фильтр

Comment: Вы имели ввиду как то так? 
    $output=do_shortcode( $output);
    return $output;

Comment: Это отличный фильтр! но к сожалению get_bloginfo('name'); по умолчанию вызывается со значением $filter='raw' и результат не фильтруется через bloginfo

Comment: я всю голову себе сломал как это сделано в qtranslate-x

Comment: Да, конечно. Исправил ошибку в ответе.

Comment: Насчет raw вы не правы. Посмотрите код get_bloginfo в wp-includes/general-template.php

Comment: Касательно qtranslate-x - это уже второй вопрос. Оформите его отдельно.

Comment: в файле general-template.php строка -  function get_bloginfo( $show = '', $filter = 'raw' ) и в документации написано По умолчанию: 'raw', и на практике тоже так выходит(

Comment: я думаю в сторону get_option('name'), но не знаю что можно сделать

Comment: Эх были бы эти дискуссии бесплодными, я бы был очень рад( конечно же тест запустил, в первую очередь. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_bloginfo/ $filter
(string) (Optional) How to filter what is retrieved.
Default value: 'raw'

Comment: То есть get_bloginfo('name') выводит get_option('blogname'), а get_bloginfo('name','display') выводит bloginfo('name'), как то так(

Comment: KAGG Design я нашел ответ на вопрос, спасибо вам большое за помощь, но к сожалению вы не правы с raw. Решение которое позволит в названии использовать шорткод - add_filter( 'option_blogname', 'blogname_filter');
function blogname_filter( $output ) {
    $output=do_shortcode( $output);
    return $output;
}